# SSL Renewal issues on Apache

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm new at work and turns out SSL Certificate for our service was expired. From the SSL provider I renewed it and change of DNS CNAME was needed for "validation", after successful validation, I was given a **Certificate(CRT)**, **Intermediate/Chain files** and **CSR (Certificate Signing Request)**. Apache is used on web server where old certificate details are written in this format:

```
    SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /***/crt_code.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /***/ca_code.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /***/crt_code.csr
```

Which of these should be replaced by which of SSL provider provided files? Or am I doing this way wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yo insatalla certificate you need the key you used to create the CSR and the new certificate. Optionally you can also configure apache to server the chain (it's what lies between your certificate and the root of the chain).
You mentioned you have the certificate (crt) which is needed, the csr (which is NOT needed) and the intermediate (which is optional) but you didn't mention the keys which, like the certificate, is mandatory.
About the apache configuration:

```
#Here goes the key file
SSLCertificateKeyFile /***/mydomain.key

#Here goes the certificate file
SSLCertificateFile /***/mydomain.crt

#Here goes the intermediate
SSLCertificateChainFile /***/mydomain.chain
```